# Android "hello world" - versions

Tags: android

Starter question: My "Hello World" attempt won't run, ("No compatible targets were found"), I think this is bacause I selected the latest version for my project (2.2), and the highest AVD version is 2.0.1. Does this make sense? Can I change my project version (haven't been able to find a way to do this), or do I have to start again? If the versions are not backwards compatible, what is the best version to use for the majority of Android devices out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion is to use 1.6 as minimum version unless you really need something available only in 2.x.
To avoid excessive crowding install only one API set.